# Dynamic questionnaire in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I want to make a template for questionnaires in Flex 3, that reads dynamic XML file and creates a questionnaire. An exemplary XML:

```
<test>

<question>
  <q>Who was born earlier?</q>
  <answer value="true">Vincent van Gogh</answer>
  <answer value="false">Piet Mondrian</answer>
</question>

<question>
  <q>What color is Dutch national flag?</q>
  <answer value="false">blue, red and green</answer>
  <answer value="false">green, red and white</answer>
  <answer value="true">blue, red and white</answer>
</question>

<question>
  <q>Which season is the coldest?</q>
  <answer value="false">fall</answer>
  <answer value="true">winter</answer>
  <answer value="false">spring</answer>
  <answer value="false">summer</answer>
</question>

</test>
```

The amount of questions and answers may vary. The plan was to use nested repeaters with radio buttons (one for the questions and then another inside for the answers). I can save all question.q to an ArrayCollection, but how should I handle my answers, if there are few of them with the same "answer" tag within each question? And how can I access "value" property of each, to check if the user chose correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a domain model from the XML.  Don't skip this step because it's easy to do and more straightforward than you think.  Start by creating a simple class:

```
public class Question {
   public var question : String;
   public var answers : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

   public Question( node : XML ) {
      question = node.q.text();
      for each( var answer : XML in question.answer ) {
          answers.addItem( new Answer( answer ) );
      }
   }
}

public class Answer {
   public var text : String;
   public var correct : Boolean;

   public Answer( node : XML ) {
      text = node.text();
      correct = Boolean(node.@value);
   }
}
```

Populate an ArrayCollection of your nodes like so:

```
var questions = new ArrayCollection();
for each( var node : XML in xml.question ) {
   questions.addItem( new Question( node ) );
}
```

That's roughly it.  Then your questions array can serve as the dataProvider for the repeater.  And question.answers can serve as the repeater for the inner repeater.

Comment: Looks great, just that something doesn't work and I don't know why.. :) I created 2 files with classes Question and Answer. Then, I'm getting my xml file through HTTP Service and saving: xml = questionService.lastResult.question as XMLList; At this moment everything works fine, because I trace(xml) and it's ok. Then I try to populate an ArrayCollection using your code, but it doesn't work.. When I try to trace(questions), it's empty. Questions[0] is already out of scope. So it doesn't populate it, but why?

Comment: maybe I'm just doing something wrong with the classes? they should be in separate files, not in my main mxml file, right? and where in the tree should I place these files...? I have them now in the default package, together with my main mxml

Comment: @Cela It makes sense to separate Question and Answer into their files.  I'd just create a simple package structure for you project (com.yoursite.questionaire).  I'm sure you can come up with something.  But I don't think that's your problem.  The questions you want to find is are you entering the first for loop?  If so is it going into your second loop?  Try tracing out statements after each loop.  You might have to do xml.test.q.  I didn't test and compile my code.  I was just working from memory as best I could remember.  I also changed XMLList -> XML.  Good Luck

Comment: I made some adjustments to the code above using methods text() on the node to get the text within it.  Changed XMLList->XML just in case something is ending up null because of casting.

Comment: @Cela I suppose you should change iterator in chubbard's code in accordance with your data: `for each( var node : XML in questionService.lastResult.question ) {`

Comment: @Constantiner thanks for the idea, but I think that's not the problem. I'm saving my http service result to "xml" variable, so it should work also with chubbard's code

Comment: @chubbard ok, after adjusting, things have changed ;) btw in your Question class constructor there should be: for each(var answer : XML in node.answer), not question.answer; anyway, it wasn't even entering the loops before. now it does and saves an object Question to questions ArrayCollection. I use it as a data provider for my first repeater and get the questions by {r.currentItem.question}. the question now is what should I use as a dataprovider for the inner repeater? cause question.answers, as you suggested, gives an error: "Access of undefined property question". thanks for all your help!

Comment: ok i answered it myself :) my outer repeater id is r, my inner repeater is r2. then as a data provider for my r2 i use: {r.currentItem.answers} and the radio button label is: {r2.currentItem.text} ; Cool! I might get back to you if i have some problems on a later stage ;)

Comment: i actually do have a question... i created click event handler for each radio button and my plan was to do playerScore++ every time the user chose correctly. However, I see now that even if the button is selected already, I can still click on it more times, and even though it's not changing anything in the view, it increments the score every time.. Also, I would have to handle the situation, when the user changes his mind. So it would be way way easier to just have a Submit button and check the states of all my buttons& if they are correct only after the user clicks "submit". Is it possible?

Comment: @Cela, I suppose you should create another question for this problem. It is very inconvenient to post answers in comments especially code snippets. Thanks!

Comment: @Constantiner ok, you're right. just didn't want to create a separate question in case the answer was quick, but here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537998/how-to-check-the-state-of-a-radio-button-in-flex-3