# How to check the state of a Radio Button in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, radio-button, state

I'm working on a template for dynamic questionnaires in Flex. More detailed description in my previous thread [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523081/dynamic-questionnaire-in-flex)

To create the questionnaire, I use nested repeaters - one for the questions and one for the answers (as their amount may vary).

```
<mx:Repeater id="r" dataProvider="{questions}">
   <mx:Label text="{r.currentItem.question}" width="200"/>
      <mx:Repeater id="r2" dataProvider="{r.currentItem.answers}">
         <mx:RadioButton label="{r2.currentItem.text}" width="200"                                          
          click="answerHandler(event, event.currentTarget.getRepeaterItem())"/>
      </mx:Repeater>
</mx:Repeater>
```

To understand my data providers, it's probably best to check the answer for my previous thread - easier than if I try to explain it here.

The question here is... As you can see, I created click event handler for each radio button and my plan was to do playerScore++ every time the user chose correctly (which can be achieved by checking the Boolean property "correct" of sent RepeaterItem).

However, I see now that even if the button is selected already, I can still click on it more times, and even though it's not changing anything in the view, it increments the score every time.. I would also have to handle situation in which the user changes his mind (I could give + points for each good answer and - points for wrong, but this would mean, that if the user chose more wrong answers, my score will be negative and I don't want it).

So it would be way way easier to just have a Submit button and check the states of all my buttons and if they are correct only after the user clicks "submit". Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to refer to the [following sample](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/05/28/displaying-radiobutton-controls-using-the-repeater-in-flex/) and add `RadioButtonGroup` to your repeater groups and listen to `change` events instead of `click`. You can listen `change` event right in `RadioButtonGroup` and check `if (radioGroup.selectedValue.correct)` for correctness of new selection. See [corresponding documentation](http://www.igorcosta.com/flex3/doc/mx/controls/RadioButtonGroup.html).

To have possibility to assign radiogroups unique name you have to extract inner repeater with answers into separate component. Breaking your application into smaller components can make your application more clear and readable. You can treat every MXML file as a class (as in OOP) but in declarative form. And to tell the true every MXML component is a class which inherited from root-node-class.

Lets look at the code.

First, our inner component which serves answers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="rightAnswerEvent", type="AnswerEvent")]
    </mx:Metadata>
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        public var answers:ArrayCollection;

        protected function answerGroup_changeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            if (answerGroup.selectedValue.correct)
                dispatchEvent(new AnswerEvent(AnswerEvent.RIGHT_ANSWER_EVENT));
        }
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:RadioButtonGroup change="answerGroup_changeHandler(event)" id="answerGroup" />
    <mx:Repeater dataProvider="{answers}" id="answersRepeater">
        <mx:RadioButton group="{answerGroup}" label="{answersRepeater.currentItem.text}"
            value="{answersRepeater.currentItem}" />
    </mx:Repeater>
</mx:VBox>
```

It gets `answers` collection as input and fires our custom event to inform some components about right answer (see `Metadata` tag).

Our custom event is pretty simple an looks like the following:

```
package
{
import flash.events.Event;

public class AnswerEvent extends Event
{
    public static const RIGHT_ANSWER_EVENT:String = "rightAnswerEvent";

    public function AnswerEvent(type:String)
    {
        super(type);
    }
}
}
```

So now our top level component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application layout="vertical" xmlns:local="*"
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        private var questions:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        [Bindable]
        private var scoreCounter:int;
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Label text="{'Score ' + scoreCounter}" />
    <mx:Repeater dataProvider="{questions}" id="questionRepeater">
        <mx:Label text="{questionRepeater.currentItem.question}" />
        <local:AnswerGroup answers="{questionRepeater.currentItem.answers}" rightAnswerEvent="scoreCounter++" />
    </mx:Repeater>
</mx:Application>
```

I omitted initialization code to populate our `Question` and `Answer` domain objects with data from XML (see previous thread).

So now we have compact modularized code where every part solves its own task.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Constantiner hmm but how can I create as many groups as questions? cause if I create a RadioButtonGroup outside of my outer repeater, I get only one group. if I try to create it already within the first repeater, I get an error: "Unable to generate initialization code within Repeater, due to id or data binding on a component that is not a visual child." To be able to access each of the groups, I would have to give each a different id. But is it even possible to do it when using a Repeater?

Comment: @Cela I suggest you to extract inner repeater group in a separate MXML component.

Comment: @Constantin I'm really just a beginner... could you explain it more? how should my separate component look like and how would I reference it? I tried to do it, but i just get tons of errors. could you please give the answer according to my mxml code I showed in my question? thanks..

Comment: @Cela I've edited my answer providing some code to illustrate my point.

Comment: @Constantiner awesome! thanks a million times! just one small thing... I want the user to get +1 if it was a correct answer and 0 if wrong. there's one situation, when this won't work: if the user chose correct (so he gets +1), then changed his mind and chose wrong. however, he still has this +1 from his previous answer.. can I "remember" what was the previous choice within each group and if the answer is wrong, it checks if it was correct before and in this case decrements the score? I'll try to think myself how to do it, but if you had a moment to explain that, I'd be in your debt forever!:)

Comment: You can add some `public var isCorrect:Boolean` field in `AnswerGroup` component (which sets in `answerGroup_changeHandler` handler) and then in main container just loop all repeater's children to have sum. The looping should be performed as reaction on `rightAnswerEvent` event.

Comment: too late ;) I found a solution like this: I extended AnswerEvent to also an option of WRONG_ANSWER_EVENT and in AnswerGroup component I'm checking if the value is correct. If yes, then except for dispatching rightAnswerEvent, I save "true" to a var previous. If it's not correct, it checks what's the value of previous and if it's set to "true", i dispatch wrongAnswerEvent (which makes scoreCounter--) and set previous="false". Works just fine! Once again, thanks for all your help! Would never do it myself.. :)